# Angular JS ternary operator inside div tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

Am using a div condition as shown below

```
<div data-index="5" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 tiles ${ {{myvariable.data}} ? 'hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-xs hidden-sm':''}" data-myapp-detail="somexyz">
```

Where the `{{myvariable.data}}` is giving problem when it is becomes "false".
 is there any angular js condition that i can initiate a variable based on the `{{myvariable.data}}` and use that variable in div tag ternary condition.

Where as if i keep boolean value **false** directly instead of `{{myvariable.data}}` it works as expected.

```
<div data-index="5" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 tiles ${ false ? 'hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-xs hidden-sm':''}" data-myapp-detail="somexyz">
```

Comment: Use for this NgClass https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Angular2

```
<div data-index="5" 
  class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 tiles"
  [ngClass]="myvariable.data ? 'hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-xs hidden-sm':''" 
  data-myapp-detail="somexyz">
```

or

```
<div data-index="5" 
  class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 tiles"
  [ngClass]="myvariable.data ? ['hidden-lg', 'hidden-md', 'hidden-xs', 'hidden-sm']:''" 
  data-myapp-detail="somexyz">
```

Comment: I believe some people would find the use of `[ngClass]` really confusing. Guess the brackets is only for emphasizing a point?

Comment: Is there any syntax mistake am doing here .? i tried below two variations nothing worked.
 
  `<div data-index="5" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 tiles ${[ngClass]="profDetData.isKaas ? ['hidden-lg', 'hidden-md', 'hidden-xs', 'hidden-sm']:''}" data-eyg-detail="membercard">` and
  
  `<div data-index="5" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 tiles "{[ngClass]="myvariable.data ? 'hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-xs hidden-sm':''}" data-myapp-detail="somexyz">`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove a `}` at the end of the expression (after `''`). Fixed.

Comment: Thanks that helps finally am able to manage by using
`<div data-index="5" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 tiles" data-ng-class="{'hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-xs hidden-sm': myvariable.data}" data-myapp-detail="somexyz">`

Comment: What is that supposed to be or do? I can't imagine this to add classes.

Comment: Is your question about AngularJS (1.x) or Angular2?

Comment: If **myvariable.data** is true i need to hide some set of div sections(which renders a box kind layout in my application) where by default those divs should be available and show with some set of data loaded by angularJs.

Comment: If your question is about Angular1.x then please don't add the Angular2 tag.